# Using Split with CTE to get Even and Odd Indexed value in sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I do have a list of data having members Choice and IsRightAnswer for MCQ. I want to send this list to stored procedure that I did by having ',' as delimiter. Now in stored procedure I want to have choice and IsRightAnswer into two seperate table which I tried to do by separating them by odd and even index. I got stuck into ORDERBY condition of ROW_NUMBER. How can I do it efficiently?

```
DECLARE @temp table(Choice nvarchar(500), [rowCount] int IDENTITY(1,1))
 DECLARE @tempIsRight table(IsRight bit, [rowCount] int IDENTITY(1,1))
 ;with tempChoice
as 
(
 select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '') AS RowNumber
 from  dbo.Split(@Choice,',')
 )
INSERT INTO @temp select * from tempChoice where RowNumber%2=0

;with tempIsRight
as 
(
 select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '') AS RowNumber
 from  dbo.Split(@Choice,',')
 )
INSERT INTO @tempIsRight select * from tempIsRight where RowNumber%2!=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give dummy for ORDER BY like  - (SELECT 1)

```
  DECLARE @temp table(Choice nvarchar(500), [rowCount] int IDENTITY(1,1))
     DECLARE @tempIsRight table(IsRight bit, [rowCount] int IDENTITY(1,1))
     ;with tempChoice
    as 
    (
     select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber
     from  dbo.Split(@Choice,',')
     )
    INSERT INTO @temp select * from tempChoice where RowNumber%2=0

    ;with tempIsRight
    as 
    (
     select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber
     from  dbo.Split(@Choice,',')
     )
    INSERT INTO @tempIsRight select * from tempIsRight where RowNumber%2!=0
```